# when i use vue to construct a img-slider the index fail to change with time.(i'm a green hand)

Tags: vue.js

```
 mounted(){
      this.timeAdder()
    },
    timeAdder(){
      clearInterval(this.timer)
       this.timer = setInterval(()=>{
        this.i++
        if(this.i>this.slideShow.length-1){
          this.i = 0
        }
      },1000)
    },
```

there are relevant codes . I cannot understand why it doesn't work